# Since Android 8 (Oreo) TTF Font doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, truetype

we developed an app (100000+ downloads) first in Android 5, that uses a ttf font (TrueTypeFont). Since the Android 8 upgrade our customers complain about it, because it doesnt show the font (symbols) anymore, but the ASCI code (letters, signs, numbers). But the strange thing is, that some few font-symbols are shown correctly.

This is the code which always worked untill Oreo:

```
    bt1.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/LASSU.TTF"));
    bt1.setText("`");
    bt2.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/LASSU.TTF"));
    bt2.setText("1");
    bt3.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/LASSU.TTF"));
    bt3.setText("`" + "\u02D6" + "1");
    bt4.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/LASSU.TTF"));
    bt4.setText("”È’Ø");
```

This code should have this appearance (this is for Android 5-7, the boxes are 4 buttons):

[image]

But instead it shows this (since Oreo, notice that the last button is shown correctly while the others aren't):

[image]

We thought maybe our methods are somehow deprecated now, but we didn't found a hint for that.
[Here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html) we also searched, but we didn't find a solution so far.

We would appreciate your help very much!!

Thankyou

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, using your code, applied to four `Button` widgets, using [this copy of the font](http://www.1001fonts.com/lassus-font.html), tested on a Pixel. You could try creating only one `Typeface` object, instead of four, in case that is somehow part of your problem.

Comment: I should not that I did not use `appcompat-v7`. It is possible that `Button` is fine but the `appcompat-v7` subclass for `Button` exhibits the problem. In that case, the problem may be tied to the combination of `appcompat-v7` and Android 8.x.

Comment: I wonder if that bottom 1/8th note only appears correctly because it's a "normal" Unicode character. (In which case your input `"”È’Ø"` gets magically transformed – it does not look like UTF8 or something similar.)

Comment: It seems that my ttf file was broken or locked. With your version it worked immedietly! Thankyou